# What is the Default Date Format in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my Query for creating a Table:

```
create table emp_company (Ename varchar2(20),Cname varchar2(20),Salary number,Jdate date);

insert into emp_company values (&ename,&cname,&salary,&jdate);

Enter value for ename: 'ANIL'

Enter value for cname: 'ACC'

Enter value for salary: 1500.00

Enter value for jdate: '01-05-89'

old   1: insert into emp_company values (&ename,&cname,&salary,&jdate

new   1: insert into emp_company values ('ANIL','ACC',1500.00,'01-05-

insert into emp_company values ('ANIL','ACC',1500.00,'01-05-89')
                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume this is Oracle? If this is the case then there is _not_ a default date format.

Comment: See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)

Comment: default _representation_ of date format, is particular to your session only... And it is governed by [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm)..

Comment: Don't use 2 digit year. Or did you start your IT profession after 2001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know the default date format of your database, you should [use a mask](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) and the to_date() function, like:

```
insert into emp_company values ('ANIL','ACC',1500.00,to_date('01-05-89', 'DD-MM-RR'));
```

Also, I'm not sure this is always the case, but I've never encountered an Oracle database that did not use the 'DD-MON-YY' as the default date format (so '01-MAY-89').

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can use the Oracle SQL Developer, which you can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).

You can define the date format which you want to work with:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd';
```

With this, now you can perform a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_company WHERE JDate = '2014-02-25'
```

If you want to be more specific you can define the date format like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```